# Why probabilites are not 50-50 in this simple circuit?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, ibm-quantum-devices

I am "brand new" to IBM quantum computing. Just created an account and tried my first circuit with a Hadamard applied to $|0 \rangle$ which should lead to $(|0\rangle + | 1 \rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and hence $50$ percent probability for $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ each. However, as shown in the screenshot of my screen, I am getting probabilities for $``00"$. Is it possible to talk in terms of probabilities of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$?

[image]

Comment: Related question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18531/9858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally right. For 1 qubit there should be 50% on |1⟩ and 50% on |0⟩.

As in the picture shown you get the probabilities of 1 qubit, 50/50. Therefore you need to press the Inspector, to run that simulation. (As in the picture shown)

**Result:**

[image: Press Inspector]

Comment: But why should there be a second Hadamard when I am dealing with only one? In the youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WkHEov3wwI, they use only one Hadamard

Comment: You are right. I had a mistake in reasoning. You need to run the Inspector. I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: You are welcome, sometimes the missing piece is simpler than quantum computing ;)